# Symfony Doctrine CLI Tool "Can't find path"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-console

i'm having a weird Problem with symfonys cli tool. I am trying to update my entity which i created using the cli tool (*no problems there*) and it throws this error.

Weird thing is: The given path `D:\w\Framework\AcmeBundle\Entity` is correct. The entity can be used by the framework and i don't get any errors about the path anywhere else. So the tool obviously knows the path but says it doesn't.

```
D:\w\Framework\>php app/console generate:doctrine:entities AcmeBundle:Foo
Generating entity "AcmeBundle\Entity\Foo"

[RuntimeException]
Can't find base path for "AcmeBundle\Entity\Foo" 
(path: "D:\w\vendors\AcmeBundle\Entity", 
destination: "D:\w\vendors\AcmeBundle\Entity").

doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

Anyone know this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with symfony2 on Windows, but I think your path is not correct.

You run the console command from this directory `D:\w\Framework\`

```
D:\w\Framework\>php app/console
```

But the error state this path `D:\w\vendors\`

```
(path: "D:\w\vendors\...
```

I guess the path should be `D:\w\Framework\vendors`.